# Is linear regression powerful enough for price prediction

Tags: r, regression

I know linear regression is the workhorse of machine learning. I understand the internals of it and I am playing with some real data samples.

Obviously using a simple line (polynomial degree = 1) is not very useful for most of the datasets, my understanding is that as I increase the polynomial degree I will

- Get a more accurate prediction
- Eventually will face the danger of overfiting

Now, I have been playing with R and some datasets and this is what I got...

```
stock <- EuStockMarkets[, 'DAX']
plot(stock)
model <- lm(stock ~ lm(poly(time(stock), 1, raw=TRUE)))
points(time(stock), predict(model), type="l", col="blue", lwd=2)
model10 <- lm(stock ~ poly(time(stock), 10, raw=TRUE))
points(time(stock), predict(model10), type="l", col="red", lwd=2)
text(1994, 5000, paste("Degree, blue=1, red=10"), pos=2)
```

[image: linear regression output]

Now, the red line is definately a muuuuch better fit thant the blue one, that said, two questions come to my mind

1. The red line is almost always (if not always) ascending, meaning that technically any time would be good to buy shares, that does not represent the truth (from 1994 to 1995 there are ups and downs, not to mention 1997 to 1998)
2. Does R automatically apply regularization to prevent overfiting.

I am fully aware that this is a very simplistic example (normally I would use more features, not just the date, in order to predict the price.

Would a more sophisticated tech such as neuronal network provide a better output here?

Comment: It would be an *extremely* worthwhile exercise to extend your plots (of all three curves--the data and the two fits) forward for several years.  In other words, compare the extrapolated fits to what actually occurred. The catastrophic failure of the red curve will then become evident.

Comment: @whuber sure, but the dataset I am using is limited, which leads me to the next question, given enough training examples, will linear regression (with some polynomial degree) provide a good prediction?

Comment: The answer (although to be fully correct should be carefully qualified) is a resounding and very loud no, for reasons that will become abundantly clear if you perform the exercise I suggested. Asset prices do not behave like polynomials for any appreciable periods--nor do most datasets, except those where an underlying physical theory indicates a polynomial relationship. The higher the degree of the polynomial, the worse its behavior will be.

Comment: @whuber : Good to know, then in which scenarios would be linear regression a valid approach? I understand that for example fuel consumption given the speed of a car would be a better use-case for linear regression?

Comment: Even a brief answer to that question would be book length! One might correctly, if not too helpfully, answer that linear regression is useful in *all* cases--if a suitable version of it is employed. Many familiar statistical procedures are, after all, just regression in disguise.  Every time you compute a mean or a standard deviation, for instance, you are doing linear regression.

Comment: @whuber ok, got it, going back to price prediction, which technique would you recommend then, neuronal networks? (note that I am still learning this, so do not need an exact answer) thanks!

Comment: I haven't made enough money in the markets to be qualified to answer that question.  What I have learned is that unless you are a very large, nimble, sophisticated player, then what you might make through any price prediction procedure is likely to be more than wiped out by transaction costs anyway.

Comment: @whuber just for the record, I am not trying to write software to operate in the stock market or anything like that, I am just trying to understand how powerful linear regression is, that is all. And yes, I know that if the dataset is ultra-super-mega-huge things can be actually kind of predicted at pretty much any level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31287/discussion-between-juan-antonio-gomez-moriano-and-whuber).

Comment: Linear regression is very powerful when appropriate. Otherwise its use wouldn't be so wide-spread. However, what you have there is a time series and time series data requires special considerations and methods.

Comment: And to answer your second question: No, it doesn't. R is not a magic wand.